# Elasticsearch parsing exception 400

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have been trying to amend my snippet in Python, but to no avail so far. Once I run it, the following message gets populated:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [fields].')
```

Here is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

client = Elasticsearch()
indexName = "medical"
docType = "diseases"
searchFrom = 0
searchSize = 3

searchBody = {
    "fields": ["name"],
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": '+fatigue+fever+"joint pain"',
            "fields": ["fulltext", "title^5", "name^10"]
        }
    }
}

client.search(
    index=indexName, 
    doc_type=docType,
    body=searchBody, 
    from_=searchFrom, 
    size=searchSize
)
```

I'm using elasticsearch version 7X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This refers to the property `fields` one line above the `query` property. It shouldn't be there. [Here's the dsl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html).

Comment: Many thanx. Indeed it should have not been there. Now it works.

Comment: @Janek you're welcome. Why don't you then upvote and mark answered so others could use that as well? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think "_source" is what ur looking for

replace "fields" with "_source"

```
searchBody = {
    "_source": ["name"],
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": '+fatigue+fever+"joint pain"',
            "fields": ["fulltext", "title^5", "name^10"]
        }
    }
}
```